# Find value of dict1 key1 when given dict1 key2?

Tags: python, search, dictionary, key-value, lookup-tables

I want to get the value from the key `'haz'` of the dictionary whose `'foo'` has value closest to `'barn'`.

Here is my inefficient solution:

```
data = [{'foo': 'bar', 'haz': 'bzr'}, {'foo': 'zoo', 'haz':'bnr'}]

from difflib import get_close_matches

closest = get_close_matches('barn', [elem['foo'] for elem in data])
print 'result =', [elem['haz'] for elem in data if elem['foo']==closest[0]][0]
```

What's a better solution?

Comment: I think you're going to need a different data structure besides a list of dicts.  But first, what do you mean by "closest"?  Edit distance?

Comment: i always feel that foo bar baz should be forbidden. apples and oranges ftw.

Comment: But you can't compare apples with oranges!

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from functools import partial
from operator import itemgetter

data = [
    {'foo': 'bar', 'haz': 'bzr'},
    {'foo': 'zoo', 'haz': 'bnr'},
    {'foo': 'potato', 'haz': 'test'}
]

matcher = partial(SequenceMatcher, 'barn')  # I'd find a better distance function
pairs = enumerate(map(itemgetter('foo'), data))  # Constructs index, value pairs

index, value = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: matcher(x[1]).ratio())[0]

print data[index]['haz']
```

I'd find a faster edit distance implementation, as calling `SequenceMatcher` (which `get_close_matches` does internally) isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: I tested this against my solution with the `time` command, it seems to perform consistently worse (though only by a bit) while requiring  substantially greater change.

Comment: @Maxwell: That's because it's creating a new `SequenceMatcher` object every time. Find a drop-in replacement function like `get_diff(a, b) -> float` and it'll speed things up.